# upgrading libc6 2.19 to 2.21 on debian

Tags: sql-server, debian

I want to install connect to an sql server using my debian server so I need to install msodbcsql for that to work, problem is its says

> msodbcsql : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.21) but 2.19-18+deb8u7 is to be installed

apparently I need to upgrade libc6 to 2.21 or above but I don't know how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved that by using Ubuntu instead of Debian.
Good version directly installed on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit.